# Arduino Mega: which Digital pins are already used for something?

Tags: arduino-mega, pins, digital

I got an Ethermega, and learned that Pin 13 already has a LED.

Are there other digital pins with special circuitry or already allocated to a specific function? (like usb,serial,ethernet,sd, etc)

I need about 30 inputs so I can skip some if that would avoid headaches.

Comment: Have you checked the schematic and datasheet yet?

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega , also you could try some external IO inputs with http://tronixstuff.com/2011/08/26/tutorial-maximising-your-arduinos-io-ports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D4: ChipSelect for the SD card reader (can be used if no SD is present)

D0 and D1 are Serial RX and TX (just like any other arduino)

D10: Ethernet enable line

D13: led. Led is connected via a mosfet, so it doesn't interfer (like on the uno)

D50, D51, D52: SPI for the ethernet chip and SD card

All this was found in the [schematic](https://github.com/freetronics/EtherMega/raw/master/EtherMega.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the led on pin 13, it just sits there but doesn't block anything.

You can still use the pin as a normal IO pin.

You didn't mention whether your 30 inputs are digital or analog, so let's have a look at digital input first.

I have never used the **MCP23017** mentioned by *Martynas*, but the linked article looks very interesting and I'll definitely order one of these amazing chips!

Another option might be using 8 bit PISO (*parallel in - serial out* shift registers, such as the **74HC165**. Consider this as the complement to the 75HC595 for output. These shift registers are dirt cheap (around 0.3 €), are available as DIP (important for breadboarding) and can be run via [SPI](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI).

Advantages:

- it's fast to read in 8 digital lines into a byte (why would one want to use more than a bit for the state of a digital input?)
- the shift registers can be *daisychained*, subsequent calls of [ShiftIn](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ShiftIn) allows to read all (digital) input states into a corresponding data structure (array of bytes, etc.) using just **three pins** on your Arduino.

Comment: Klaus i wanted to mention `74HC165` :) but `MCP23017` link was open already so i just copied it to give the main idea:) +1

Comment: @Martynas I think it was a splendid idea to mention the `MCP23017`! As written by John Boxall in the article that you linked: "...I think the I2C bus is underappreciated".